# ResumableUploadAbortException on gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I keep seeing the following error when using `gsutil`

```
ResumableUploadAbortException: Upload complete with 6275 additional bytes left in stream
```

The command is very simple, something like

```
gsutil cp -r <source_path> gs://<target-bucket>/<target_path>
```

with about 80 files inside `<source_path>`. There are nested folders inside `<source_path>`, as well. Changing `gsutil cp` to `gsutil -m cp` doesn't make a difference. And this error is reproducible when I run it inside a python script together with lots of a other code. However, when I run the command separately in bash, it doesn't seem to have any problem. So I wonder what could possibly be the reason to ResumableUploadAbortException, please?

Tail of debug output with `gsutil -D -m cp`

```
total_bytes_transferred: 794750002
Total bytes copied=794750002, total elapsed time=7.932 secs (95.55 MiBps)
DEBUG: Exception stack trace:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 565, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
        parallel_operations, perf_trace_token=perf_trace_token)
      File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 280, in RunNamedCommand
        return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
      File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 998, in RunCommand
        self.op_failure_count, plural_str, plural_str))
    CommandException: CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
```

Comment: What version of gsutil are you using?

Comment: @TravisHobrla, `gsutil version: 4.19`

Comment: That you can't reproduce this in bash makes it seem most likely that something in your python script may still be writing to one of the files or that the file may have not been flushed before you call `gsutil`.  How are you calling gsutil from Python?  You can collect a `gsutil -D cp` log to see if the byte ranges that gsutil is attempting to send initially match your expected file size(s).

Comment: The debug output is rather verbose, what should I be looking at? I have updated my question with the last tail of the debug log. I also trimmed my code down to only the part of `gsutil` and the problem is still reproducible. Though I think it unlikely, if it's a flushing problem, does it mean I need to use something like `sys.stdout.flush`?

Comment: Is your Python code producing the files that will be transferred?  If it is, you need make sure they're all fully flushed/closed before `gsutil` or any other utility can safely copy them.  As for the debug log, generally what you're looking for is the HTTP header like `content-range: bytes 0-999/1000` after a PUT /resumable/upload/storage request.  The size in that header should match your expected size in the source file.

Comment: I see. I will debug further. By the way, is there an easy way to find out which file is not successfully uploaded since the Exception message doesn't tell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115996/discussion-between-zyxue-and-travis-hobrla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are transferring a file that gets changed during the transfer process. In my case, the problem is that I redirect the output to a log file, while the log file is also being transferred to the cloud, which causes the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Using WSL2?

WSL has a [well known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5324) that causes the time to go out of sync.

In my case, it looks like having the time out of sync caused the `ResumableUploadAbortException`.

To fix it, just sync the time from WSL 2: `sudo nohup watch -n 10 ntpdate time.windows.com > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 0):

The `gsutil` command suggests to "delete tracker files" to fix the problem. That did indeed fix the issue for me:

```
rm -rf ~/.gsutil/tracker-files
```